# How to set custom body to Slim 3 response?

Tags: php, httpresponse, slim-3

Currently my code is like this:

```
    $newResponse = $response
        ->withStatus(200, 'Logged in!')
        ->withHeader('jwt',$jwt);
```

If I try to add **->withBody()**, it requires some kind of **Streaminterface** object, I would just like to add the Jwt token to the body since in my ReactJS the request says it is type **cors** and apparently I can't access the JWT token because the http type is cors.

```
    $newResponse = $response
        ->withStatus(200, 'Logged in!')
        ->withHeader('jwt',$jwt)
        ->withBody($jwt);
```

[Here's the image from chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FQuy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withBody()` method will return new instance of `ResponseInterface` with its body replaced with instance that you pass from its parameter. If your concern is only to write something to body then you can call `getBody()` and write your data there.

```
$newResponse = $response
    ->withStatus(200, 'Logged in!')
    ->withHeader('jwt',$jwt);
$newResponse->getBody()->write($jwt);
```